# Detecting colour of a specific x and y coordinate of an image in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, image-segmentation

I'm trying to obtain the colour of a specific coordinate on an image. For example: X is an image with size width:300 and height:300. I would like to know the colour at x:10 and y:10 coordinate. I couldn't write any code because I don't know if this is even possible in matlab?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course you can do such operations on MATLAB:

```
A = imread('yourimage.png');

X = 10;
Y = 10;

color = A(Y, X, :);
color = squeeze(color);
```

`color` will then be a row vector containing the RGB values of that pixel (from 0 to 255). Of course the `Y` image axis is oriented towards the opposite verse than the Cartesian one.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the color by manually selecting a pixel in Matlab you can do something like that:

```
A = imread('Lena.png');
imshow(A);
[x,y] = ginput(1); % Select a point on the plot
x = fix(x); y = fix(y); % Fix to nearest pixel
hold on;
plot(x,y,'bo'); % Plot the point
color = squeeze(A(x,y,:))'; % Get the color
```

and then even use something like [that](https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22325-rgb2name) to convert it to it's name. In this particular example the code would be maybe something like that:

```
A = imread('Lena.png');
h = figure;
imshow(A);
while true
    [x,y,key] = ginput(1);
    x = fix(x); y = fix(y);
    hold on;
    plot(x,y,'bo');
    color = squeeze(A(x,y,:))';
    name = rgb2name(double(color)/256);
    disp(name);
    if key == 27; break; end; % key == escape
end
close(h);
```

Have fun! ;)

Comment: Great answer. But I would recommend that you convert `color` variable to `double` instead of `uint8` in the first script. Because the intensities must be in the range [0,1], for example, [0.4, 0.6, 0].